how the output and input mechanism work on the terminal of C++ in this example
Here is the code. I input 233 twice as the Variables g and k.
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {

 
    int g, k;
    cout << "type number :";
    cin >> g;
    cout << "your number : " << g << endl;
    cout << "type another number:     ";
    cin >> k;
    cout << "your number : " << k << endl;
    int sum = g + k;
    cout << "sum is :" << sum;
    return 1;
}

why the terminal output type another number:, then accept the input233 user passed in ,finally output the 5 spaces to the begging of the 4th line. Like this:
type number :233
your number : 233
type another number:233
     your number : 233
sum is :466

instead of
the terminal output type another number:      , then accept the input 233 user passed in, finally output your number : 233 ?
In my opinion, the terminal should be like this:
type number :233
your number : 233
type another number:     233
your number : 233
sum is :466

Please tell me why my expectation is wrong ,and introduce specifically why the C++ handles space in this way and any information or key mechanism about this.
Hey guys, I just finished my investigation about this little C++program on two platform.
My operating system: Windows10 Pro 22h2
Windows OS Builds: 19045.5247
My running platform: JetBrains CLion 2024.3.1 Pro
CLion toolchains:
Bundled MinGW Version 11.0 w64
Bundled  CMake  Version 3.30.5
Bundled GDB Version 15.2(all of them is CLion bundled)
Terminal:
CLion built-in terminal
CMakeLists:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)

Here is the keypoint:  When I run this code in Visual Studio 2022(the newest version) on my PC, VS2022 terminal show the right expectaion like this:
type number :233
your number : 233
type another number:     233
your number : 233
sum is :466

Is that the error from MinGW?
But, when i change CLion toolchains from MinGW to Visual Studio, it still show the wrong output in the terminal bundled by CLion:
type another number:233
     your number : 233

Maybe this situation can be reproduced now.

I got the output you had in your expectation, which is also what I expected.  If you are seeing something else, it may depend on your operating system, or your platform, or your compiler, or your terminal program, or your terminal's shell, or which C++ standard you are using.

When characters appear on your terminal is not something that is directly controlled by C++ (how could it be). In particular when you hit a key and when that character is echoed to the terminal is not something your program has any control over. If you are hitting keys at the same time as your program is outputing characters things are going to be a bit unpredictable.

It looks to me that your program should behave the way you expect it to. Maybe we're seeing a broken cin/cout implementation. Could you please give specifics about your system: OS, compiler, version, exact parameters you use to compile the source, etc.?

@Eljay  I updated all information about the environment this code run in. Hope for your view.

@john  I updated all information about the environment this code run in. Hope for your opinion.

@joker-Dmmm In my comment I said ' If you are hitting keys at the same time as your program is outputing characters ...'. You haven't clarified whether that was the case or not, so I have no further comment. But I can confidentally state that you have not found a bug in MinGW. My guess is that you are running your program in a way that makes the output unpredicatable, and therefore it's no surprise that you find different output with different compilers.

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int g, k;
    cout << "type number :";
    cin >> g;
    cout << "your number : " << g << endl;
    cout << "type another number:     " << flush;  // Add flush
    cin >> k;
    cout << "your number : " << k << endl;
    int sum = g + k;
    cout << "sum is :" << sum;
    return 1;
}

This works for me and controls when the buffered data will actually be flushed.  There is no guarantee when the data will be flushed so calling flush explicitly will control it.  The endl calls force cout to be flushed in addition to inserting a new line.

A quick websearch showed me at multiple places that cin and cout are tie()'d together by default, meaning that a read from cin automatically flushes cout beforehand. So either all those sources are wrong, or I'm overlooking something, or further explanation is needed.

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout I don't see a specification of when the flush happens so it may be possible that the flush happens when the operation on cin completes which may lead to this behavior which can be mitigated by calling flush explicitly

It literally says on that page: "By specification of std::cin, std::cin.tie() returns &std::cout. This means that any input operation on std::cin executes std::cout.flush() [...]" It's not specified what all the exact scenarios when a flush occurs are, but specifies that a read from cin is one of them. Therefore I still don't understand what's going on.

@egmont your quotes are accurate as are my statements. It is not specified whether the flush happens at the beginning, end, or other time with respect to operations on cin so speculating that it happens when the read completes is valid. I don’t fully understand either but am proposing a possible explanation which the OP requested

You are right, and this could be the missing bit. (If so then you need to "print" a flush before every cin read because there's no guarantee that the others can't behave unexpectedly on other systems.) But, to be honest, if the actual specification does not tell that the flush needs to happen before the read then I don't see the point in this "tie" feature at all.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie says "[...] flush() is called on the tied stream before any input/output operation on *this", and similarly, https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/tie/ says "The tied stream is an output stream object which is flushed before each i/o operation in this stream object." Note the word "before" in both. So, no, this wasn't the missing bit, and I'm still puzzled.

That makes this seem like unusual terminal behavior or a non-conforming implementation. Thanks for continuing to dig.  A manual flush should not be needed but may solve his problem

Indeed, a non-conforming cin/cout implementation is my current suspicion too, as per my comment on the original question. Would be lovely to hear details about the system, as well as whether a manual flush solves the problem.

As for a possible unusual (buggy) terminal behavior, I find that extremely unlikely: the terminal would have to shuffle around the incoming characters, and delay processing those spaces until after processing "233" plus the newline (as typed by the user and echoed back by the kernel) which arrive on that very same channel. Such kind of a bug is extremely hard to introduce accidentally and would likely cause serious display glitches across plenty of apps.

Yet another possibility to consider: Maybe OP made a mistake whle coming up with a minimal reproducible example and stripped off something needed to trigger the bug, and the shown code isn't actually buggy. After all, #include <iomanip> is unnecessary, probably a leftover while stripping a larger real-life example that's buggy. Maybe there was a sleep before printing the spaces and he typed ahead "233" during that wait. Dunno, just a wild guess.

Thanks for your reply. this situation can be reproduced now

It is really strange that when I run your code on Clion, It still show :  your number : 233    (4 spaces are before "your")
But on VS2022, it work. Even I run my code ,it still work. You can see the detail on the post I updated.

@egmont   Thanks for your reply. this situation can be reproduced specifically now. You can see the detail on the post I updated. Hope for your opinion.

Older C++ didn't tie the flushing of cout with cin.  Maybe the OP is using an older C++.

I got the output of your expectation. Line number 13 of your code, also the extra spaces are sent directly to the terminal before waiting for the input. To achieve specific formatting, you must structure your code explicitly.
int g, k;
cout << "type number :";
cin >> g;
cout << "your number : " << g << endl;
cout << "type another number:";
cin >> k;
cout << "     your number : " << k << endl;
int sum = g + k;
cout << "sum is :" << sum;
return 1;


You can't reproduce OP's problem, but you show a piece of code that, by intent, produces the broken result that OP has shown. Sorry but how is this an answer to the question??

I tried to explain to achieve specific formatting to get the expected result.  What do you think is the correct answer to this problem?

Unfortunately I don't know. I wish I could help OP but I cannot, and I couldn't reproduce the problem. I spent a couple of minutes researching cin/cout's buffering, and (based on this extremely limited knowledge) I don't understand why OP's code doesn't produce the desired result for them. But showing a code that is supposed to produce the broken, undesired result is definitely not the answer, nor helps us getting closer to understand the discrepancy.

Thanks for your reply. this situation can be reproduced now
